# React Native application crashes when using reducer: "Render error; Invalid hook call."

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native application, and I am getting this error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeoZe.jpg). I am trying to scan devices via bluetooth and the problem seems to be that the reducer does not work properly. I have tried everything to fix it, but nothing works.

Here is my code:

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Button, FlatList, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { BleManager, Device } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {DeviceCard} from 'c:/Users/Vukmi/LearningCar/components/DeviceCard';
import { requestLocationPermission } from './components/user_permission';

const manager = new BleManager();

// Reducer to add only the devices which have not been added yet
// Indeed, when the bleManager searches for devices, each time it detects a ble device, it returns the ble device even if this one has already been returned
const reducer = (
  state: Device[],
  action: { type: 'ADD_DEVICE'; payload: Device } | { type: 'CLEAR' },
): Device[] => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_DEVICE':
      const { payload: device } = action;

      // check if the detected device is not already added to the list
      if (device && !state.find((dev) => dev.id === device.id)) {
        return [...state, device];
      }
      return state;
    case 'CLEAR':
      return [];
    default:
      return state; 
  }
};

const App = () => {
  //const checkUserPermission = async () => {
  //  let userPermission = requestLocationPermission();
  //  while(!userPermission){
  //    userPermission = requestLocationPermission();
  //  }
  //} 
  //checkUserPermission();
  

    // reducer to store and display detected ble devices
  const [scannedDevices, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  // state to give the user a feedback about the manager scanning devices
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const scanDevices = () => {
    // display the Activityindicator
    setIsLoading(true);
 
    // scan devices
    manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, scannedDevice) => {
      if (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      }
      
      // if a device is detected add the device to the list by dispatching the action into the reducer
      if (scannedDevice) {
          dispatch({type: "ADD_DEVICE", payload: scannedDevice})
      }
    });

    // stop scanning devices after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      manager.stopDeviceScan();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
  };
  
    const ListHeaderComponent = () => (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Devices</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <Button
          title="Clear devices"
          onPress={() => dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR' })}
        />
        {isLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator color={'teal'} size={25} />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <Button title="Scan devices" onPress={scanDevices} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={scannedDevices}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <DeviceCard device={item} />}
        ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.red
  },
  activityIndicatorContainer: { marginVertical: 6 },
});

export default App;
```

DeviceCard.tsx:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Device } from "react-native-ble-plx";
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type DeviceCardProps = {
    device: Device;
};

  const DeviceCard = ({ device }: DeviceCardProps) => {
    console.log("I am here!");
    const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();

    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
          // is the device connected?
      device.isConnected().then(() => setIsConnected(true));
    }, [device]);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        // navigate to the Device Screen
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Device', { device })}>
        <Text>{Id : ${device.id}}</Text>
        <Text>{Name : ${device.name}}</Text>
        <Text>{Is connected : ${isConnected}}</Text>
        <Text>{RSSI : ${device.rssi}}</Text>
        <Text>{Manufacturer : ${device.manufacturerData?.replace(/[=]/g, '')}}</Text>
        <Text>{ServiceData : ${device.serviceData}}</Text>
        <Text>{UUIDS : ${device.serviceUUIDs}}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      marginBottom: 12,
      borderRadius: 16,
      shadowColor: 'rgba(60,64,67,0.3)',
      shadowOpacity: 0.4,
      shadowRadius: 10,
      elevation: 4,
      padding: 12,
    },
  });

  export { DeviceCard };
```

user_permission.tsx:

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";

export async function requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, {
          title: 'Location permission for bluetooth scanning',
          message: 'whatever',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      ); 
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('Location permission for bluetooth scanning granted');
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('Location permission for bluetooth scanning revoked');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: To help others understand your issue and to aid in finding a solution I would recommend you provide a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you are facing. It's possible that the process of doing so sheds new light on the problem at hand. Regardless it will aid others in helping you. Please consider this when next posting a question, to aid in solving your future problems as quickly as possible. :)

Comment: Ok, I am working on it, thank you very much! :)